# Android: set alarm to fire everyday except the weekends

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I have read lots of articles, however I did not find/or just missed an answer on my specific quiestion, it is strange cause I think I am trying to implement a common case.
Well, what I whant is to set alarm to fire everyday except the weekends, so from monday-friday at some specific time.

Currently I do next:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

Intent intent = creating an Intent here
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

as far as I understand next code will fire an alarm on the time I have specified and do it every day, because of AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.

I thought about doing next to accomplish my task:

```
  for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
  }
```

But I am not sure, about the correctness of this logic.
Can you please
1. correct me, if I missed something
2. suggest some proper solution or just your thoughts to accomplish my task

**Update:**

Well, I have thought about next:
what if I

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
```

and then

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 5, pendingIntent);
```

so as a result I will be setting initial day to Monday and repeat it 5 times, so Monday-Friday, no matter what is the current date, when user is setting an alarm, is it correct or I am missing smth?
Btw, how can I update setRepeating to set it to repeat every week, not only one?

**Update1:**

I guess I understood my error, by using the above code, I will do some strange things, so the init day is Monday, however the repeat interval is once in 5 days, not every day from Monday-Friday.

Comment: You can check if the day is `SATURDAY` or `SUNDAY` after adding the time to `calendar`, then decide to not to set the alarm. However, you cannot use `setRepeating()` as it cannot check the day.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Well I do not understand how can I set the start day to be Monday and repeate alarm everyday except weekends, no matter what is the current day, when user sets the alarm

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your edit (Update1) and it seems that it is much simpler than my idea. I was thinking to use `.set()` with `Calendar` set to weekdays manually, but it is very troublesome. By the way, I recommend you to post your finding as the answer of this post. It's okay (and recommended!) for an asker to answer his/her own question here :)

Comment: Thanks:) moved "updates" into answer section

Comment: your for loop is wrong   for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
  } ...it loop 1 throungh 5 only..It should be  for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen you are missing that I was trying to avoid Saturday and Sunday, that is why I was using 1->5, not 1->7

Comment: Btw, maybe you know, use of for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
  } and use of isWeekend is the same talking about handle of only Monday-Friday or not?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only solution is to set

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

and in the fire handler, which I have specified in the Intent constructor, check the current day and avoid notification if it is Saturday or Sunday.

```
...
  if(intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false) && !isWeekend())
    showNotification();
...

  private boolean isWeekend() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    return (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY);
  }
```

Btw, tell me please, I have set the alarm in repeat mode, for the first time it did fire, then I open emulator settings and manually move date to tomorrow and time back, but no alarm notification is fired, is it smth with emulator or I have some errors in code?